# Access API data with Firebase Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, api, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to pull data from an API and store it in a variable.
I'm using firebase functions, IEXCloud and node.js, but I can't access the data in the body.
The link works when I use it on its own and if I remove .body from the link, then the link is send to the browser.

This is what I have:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const sA = "https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/";
const key = "(API-Key)";

exports.symbol = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const symbol = (`${sA}stock/aapl/quote?token=${key}`).body;
  response.send(symbol);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not calling any API here `const symbol = (`${sA}stock/aapl/quote?token=${key}`).body;`.

Did you mean to call `fetch()`:

```
exports.symbol = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  return fetch(`${sA}stock/aapl/quote?token=${key}`).then((res) => {
    symbol = res.body;
    response.send(symbol);
  });
});
```

Comment: This did not solve it completely, but that was my mistake. I though that Firebase functions had to start with the "exports." syntact but that was not the case. 
Your feedback helped guide me to use fetch(), and that turned out to be what i needed (as well as restructuring the whole arrangement) :).

The result looks like this:

Comment: `const app = express();
app.use(cors({origin: true}));

app.get("/", (request, response) => {
  fetch(`${sA}stock/aapl/quote${key}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        console.log("Symbol:");
        console.log(json["symbol"]);
        console.log("Latest price:");
        console.log(json["extendedPriceTime"]);
        response.send(json);
     });
});

exports.widgets = functions.https.onRequest(app);`